# rPy2 S3 method plot not working for robCompositions package

Tags: python, r, plot, rpy2

I am trying to generate a plot from the `robCompositions` package in `R`. I am working with the example shown [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/robCompositions/man/clustCoDa.html). Details about the package are found [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/robCompositions/index.html).

This plot is produced following some clustering analysis with the `robCompositions` package.

My system is Ubuntu 16.10 64-bit. I set my `R` working directory using:

```
setwd('/home/UserRob/Downloads')
```

I installed the package and dependencies using:

```
install.packages(c('data.table','pls','robCompositions'))
```

I can execute the code in this example, in `R`, using the following `rtest.R` file:

```
library(robCompositions)
data(expenditures)
x <- expenditures
rr3 <- clustCoDa(x, k=6, distMethod = "Aitchison", method = "single",
transformation = "identity", scale = "none")
plot(rr3)
dev.off()
```

When I execute this in Ubuntu with `Rscript /home/UserRob/Downloads/rtest.R`, I get a plot saved to `/home/UserRob/Downloads/Rplots.pdf`.

I tried to run this code in `rPy2` with the following code in `rtest.py`:

```
from rpy2.robjects import r
r.library('robCompositions')
r('data')('expenditures')
x = r('expenditures')
rr3 = r('clustCoDa')(x,k=6,distMethod='Aitchison',method='single',scale='none',
transformation='identity')
r('plot')(rr3)
```

When I execute this using `python /home/UserRob/Downloads/rtest.py`, the plot is not produced. The Python variable `rr3` is the same as that from the `R` usage above. So, the code runs correctly except for the last line - `r('plot')(rr3)`. It appears that the `r('plot')` command is not running at all. I also tried the following in `rPy2`:

```
from rpy2 import robjects
grdevices = importr("grDevices")
graphics = importr("graphics")
from rpy2.robjects import r
r.library('robCompositions')
r('data')('expenditures')
x = r('expenditures')
rr3 = r('clustCoDa')(x,k=6,distMethod='Aitchison',method='single',scale='none',
transformation='identity')
grdevices.png("rtest.png")
graphics.plot(rr3)
grdevices.dev_off()
```

However, this also gave me the same result - the plot is not saved to `rtest.png`. All the code before the line `graphics.plot(rr3)` appears to run correctly.

In the documentation for [R's OOPs](http://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/robjects_oop.html), I think I am using `plot()` the same way as `plot.lm()` shown. It seems that `plot()` is an S3 method for the class for class `clustCoDa` (as documented [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/robCompositions/man/clustCoDa.html)) and I just need to use `plot()` - in line 6 of the doc, it actually just links to the usual `plot()` [function](https://rdrr.io/r/graphics/plot.html).

**Question:**

Is there a problem with the `plot()` function in `rPy2`?

**EDIT:**

I have duplicated the problem in `Windows 7 64-bit`. Here are the details:

***Python details:***

- `Python 2.7.8`

***R details:***

- `R x64 3.3.2`
- personal library folder: `C:\Users\UserRob\Documents\R\win-library\3.3`

***Windows Environment Variables:***

```
R_USER: C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\rpy2
R_LIBS: C:\Users\UserRob\Documents\R\win-library\3.3
R_HOME: C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.2
```

***My*** `rtest_win.py` ***file:***

```
from rpy2.robjects import r
r('.libPaths( c( .libPaths(), "C:/Users/UserRob/Documents/R/win-library/3.3") )')
r.library('robCompositions')
r('data')('expenditures')
x = r('expenditures')
rr3 = r('clustCoDa')(x,k=6,distMethod='Aitchison',method='single',scale='none',
transformation='identity')
r('plot')(rr3)
```

As with Linux, the code runs but the `plot()` command does not produce a file. This leads me to suspect that the problem is with `rPy2`.i.e. `rPy2` cannot generate the plot with the `robCompositions` package's `plot()` S3 method.

Comment: I wish someone would port robComposition across to python!